# LLC resonant converter simulation

Tags: dc-dc-converter

For an LLC resonant circuit, why when the resonant current is superimposed with the magnetizing current the voltage of the diodes on the secondary side oscillates when these diodes are wired in parallel with a capacitor? And these capacitor resonate with what and why?

Comment: Your schematic is required.

Comment: You can already have a look at a recent [seminar](http://powersimtof.com/Downloads/PPTs/Introduction%20to%20the%20LLC%20Converter.pdf) I posted on the control of the LLC converter. A quick simulation of the said converter will let you explore the topology in details. You can download my [ready-made templates](http://powersimtof.com/Downloads/Book/Christophe%20Basso%20SIMPLIS%20Collection.pdf) and start simulating immediately with the free demo from SIMPLIS.

Comment: Thinx you for your answer

Comment: Kader - Hi, You wrote an "answer" (it was empty, so it has been deleted). However, since you asked the question, unless you are writing the *full & final* answer to your own question (i.e. you don't need further help & you solved the problem yourself using a different solution than any other answer) please *don't* use the box labeled "Your Answer" below. Instead, to add more info / clarification for everyone, please [edit] the question. Or *comment* to respond to an answer from someone else, if your response is specific to that answer. || Please see the [tour] & [help] for more rules. Thanks

Comment: Thinx u for your help